# Best way to carry & modify a variable through various instances and functions?

Tags: php, global-variables, session-variables

I'm looking for the "best practice" way to achieve a message / notification system. I'm using an OOP-based approach for the script and would like to do something along the lines of this:

```
if(!$something)
   $messages->add('Something doesn\'t exist!');
```

The add() method in the messages class looks somewhat like this:

```
class messages {
   public function add($new) {
      $messages = $THIS_IS_WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR; //array

      $messages[] = $new;
      $THIS_IS_WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR = $messages;
   }
}
```

In the end, there is a method in which reads out $messages and returns every message as nicely formatted HTML.

So the questions is - what type of variable should I be using for `$THIS_IS_WHAT_IM_LOOKING_FOR`?

- I don't want to make this use the database. Querying the db every time just for some messages that occur at runtime and disappear after 5 seconds just seems like overkill.
- Using global constants for this is apparently worst practice, since constants are not meant to be variables that change over time. I don't even know if it would work.
- I don't want to always pass in and return the existing `$messages` array through the method every time I want to add a new message.
- I even tried using a session var for this, but that is obviously not suited for this purpose at all (it will always be 1 pageload too late).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Added after I caused some confusion with the above...
The `$messages` array should be global: I need to be able to add to it through various different classes as well as at the top-level of the whole script.

The best comparison that comes to mind is to use a database to store all the messages that occur at runtime, and when it's output-time, query the database and output every message. The exception to this comparison is just that the lifetime of the $messages array is the page load (they accumulate during page load, and vanish right after).

So, for example, say I have 10 different actions running one after the other in the script. Each one of these actions make use of a different class. Each one of these classes should be able to post to `$messages->add()`. After all 10 actions have run, it's "output time", and the $messages array can contain up to 10 different messages which were added via all the different classes.

I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What *kind* of messages are we talking about here? What kind of scope and timeframe do they exist in?

If you have two items `$messageOne = new Message();` and `$messageTwo = new Message();`, do they share data when you go `$messageOne->add("Oh noes");`?

Comment: Darien - I edited my post above to explain. It's "yes" to your last question: they share data. The scope is the entire script until headers are being sent. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you're going to have a global messages array (and this, having global variables, is probably not a library), why don't you simply add to it using `$messages[] = "Some text";`? It seems to be a bit of a waste of a class to do this super-simple operation that's going to be used in only a single script.

Comment: I wanted to use a class because at one point, I want to implement multiple languages. If I have everything in one class, I can later pass it all through a `translate` function. I'm also generally a little hesitant to use global variables in this manner... I was looking for a static variable that only exists in the `message` class, can be added to from anywhere at any time, and can only be rendered from that class. I'm looking into dependency injection now (re: Matthew) - I think the main culprit is my approach of re-instantiating dependencies for every class, which makes static vars useless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear about what you want to do, but a good way would be to simply use a private variable:

```
class messages {
   private $messages = array();
   public function add($new) {
     $this->messages[] = $new;
   }
   public function output() {
     // Whatever; e.g. a foreach loop that echoes all the messages
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need either a instance field.

Comment: I've looked at static variables, but haven't found a way to implement them for this purpose yet. Would you mind posting a quick example of how exactly I can implement that? Thanks.

Comment: I actually re-read your question, and now I'm not clear what you want.  Should the message array be per instance, or is it shared by the whole class?  I assume it does need to be used outside add.

Comment: The message array should be global (shared by the whole class), and it should be modified via add() in multiple instances. I need to be able to call $message->add() as many times as I like, anywhere in the script, and each time the array is getting a new key added to it. In the end, I need to be able to access the $messages array in order to output it as HTML. Sorry for the confustion, I hope this makes sense now :)

Comment: Will you have more than one messages object (instance) per script?  If so, why?

Comment: Matthew - I'm instantiating the object in index.php, and then again in the __construct() method of each class that uses the object, so that I can access it like $this->message->add() from within that foreign class. Is there a better way?

Comment: It actually sounds like you only need one object for now, and that you should pass it to the constructor of classes that use it [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  There is no point in constructing multiple objects that have the exact same state.  So I think I agree with hsource.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm looking into it now and will post back.